# Run SQL Statement in Access using VBA code

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I can't figure out what is wrong in this,
I'm collecting search criteria from a Form to use it in search.

The SQL line stored like this : (strWhere is the collected info from the Form)

> SQLst = "SELECT Deposits.Fines, Deposits.[Deposit Value], Deposits.[Deposit Date], Deposits.Depositor, Info.Tower, Deposits.[Account Number] FROM Info, Deposits Where " & strWhere & ";"

The final SQL statement looks like this:

> SELECT Deposits.Fines, Deposits.[Deposit Value], Deposits.[Deposit Date], Deposits.Depositor, Info.Tower, Deposits.[Account Number] FROM Info, Deposits Where ([Account Number] = "1234");

Now After I run the Line using this command (SQLst is the SQL Line up)

> DoCmd.OpenQuery SQLst

I get this message:

[image]

Comment: Try replacing the double quotes (`"`) in the `WHERE` clause with single quotes (`'`).

Comment: sorry edited it, i put wrong error message

Comment: OK, Finally found a topic that is talking about what i need, as a first test i can say it's acceptable. in case any one needed it (check post #7)..... Also is there a way in access to accomplish that without using vba or sql ( query that take more than one criteria from a form ) ?!                                          http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=225700

Answer (score 5):

Not `DoCmd.OpenQuery SQLst`, that is for saved queries, not SQL strings. You need:

```
' Best to use a separate instance, so you can get record counts etc.
Set db = CurrentDB
```

For action queries:

```
db.Execute SQLst, dbFailOnerror
```

For SELECT queries, you can either use a recordset or update or create a query.

```
Set rs = db.Openrecordset(SQLst)

' This query does not exist
Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("MyQuery", SQLst)
```

I doubt that the account number is text, so:

```
 ([Account Number] = 1234);
```

Quotes are used for text-type fields / columns, numbers are as is and dates are delimited with hash (#).

Comment: cc: @user1641782 ...and, as is so often repeated here and elsewhere, using a parameterized query is always better than "SQL glue-up".

Comment: thanks, for the reply, i tried it but it gived me an error, when i searched for it, found this http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/HV080760050.aspx

Comment: It seems that there is no way i can run the select with execute command.your comment about the quotes was useful it did made some problem while testing. and also thanks for Gord.